# Key-combination on Emacs + nRepl + ClojureMode

Tags: macos, emacs, clojure, nrepl

I'm new to the Emacs + Lein + nRepl + ClojureMode combination and seem to be at a loss as to why I cannot run the C-c C-, key combination in a clojure program buffer. It simply does not take the C-,. Other shortcuts, such as C-c C-k work just fine.

I'm using the Emacs from the Terminal OS X, on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion, if one might find that useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Which modes to do see enabled fron your mode-line please?

Comment: F1  core_test.clj   All L6     (Clojure nREPL) -> I guess Clojure nRepl is what you are interested in (told you I'm new to emacs :) )

Comment: Mhh just looking in my own Emacs. <kbd>C-c C-,</kbd> is not defined. What did you expect from that key sequence? If you were expecting jumping to the definition of the symbol at point, I would suggest to try <kbd>M-.</kbd> instead. See https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el

Comment: I meant : https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el#keys

Comment: Well, I was just trying to follow a walkthrough, this one to be exact: http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/emacs.html. What I've come up with is that it was a mistake in the first place, it should have been [C-c ,] and as for why C-, doesn't get called at all, it's because the Terminal will not send any sequence for that key combination. I tested this with C-h k, then trying to see if C-,  gets anything, even a "No mapping" result. Thank you very much for your time.